# Scikit-learn: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

So, I was working on a pipeline, and I stumbled upon this error when fitting it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shawn/Documents/temp/bool_issue.py", line 7, in <module>
    _assert_all_finite(array, False)
  File "C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 103, in _assert_all_finite
    if _object_dtype_isnan(X).any():
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
```

*This is actually a some custom code to test the issue, see below*

Following the traceback, I see that `_object_dtype_isnan()` takes a numpy array, and returns another numpy array, in the form of a boolean mask (an array of booleans).
However, for some reason, it sometimes returns a boolean directly instead.

Code to reproduce the error:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils.validation import _assert_all_finite

bad_array = np.array(['F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', pd.NA, 'F', 'M'], dtype='object')

_assert_all_finite(bad_array, False)  # Raises AttributeError
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further investigation, I found out that was because some `pd.NA` got in my dataset.
Replacing them with `None` works just fine !

```py
# For my original pandas DataFrame
X.replace(to_replace=pd.NA, value=None, inplace=True)
```

From my understanding (I didn't check, just guessing), numpy won't try to do the elementwise comparison because there are external objects inside, so instead it will perform a whole comparison of the array.
Also, working around the mask with `pd.NA` seems to be a mess:

```
>>> array = np.array(['F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', pd.NA, 'F', 'M'], dtype='object')
>>> mask = np.equal(array, np.array(['F', ] * len(array)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shawn/Documents/temp/bool_issue.py", line 7, in <module>
    mask = np.equal(array, np.array(['F', ] * len(array)))
  File "pandas\_libs\missing.pyx", line 360, in pandas._libs.missing.NAType.__bool__
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Therefore, if you have a trick for replacing them in a numpy array, please share !

While this is issue is not directly linked to scikit-learn, but rather the way numpy works, that's how I found it, so I'll tag it anyway :shrug: :)

Answer (score 3):

So, I had the same exact error once again recently, but this time, it didn't work with `None`.

Long story short, updating scikit-learn from 0.23.2 to 0.24.2 solved the issue :)